# How to solve error 400, in React + Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

to everyone, i have a problem about a request to the server. I get error 400, but i don't understand where is the problem, i checked my code thousand times and it looks like all good.
Basically, with this request i get the "order number".

This is the reducer:

```
    const initialState = {
  status: "STALE",
};

export const orderObjectReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  if (action.type === "SEND_ORDER_FAILED") {
    return { status: "FAILED" };
  }
  if (action.type === "SEND_ORDER_IS_LOADING") {
    return {
      status: "LOADING",
    };
  }
  if (action.type === "SEND_ORDER_STALE") {
    return {
      status: "STALE",
    };
  }
  if (action.type === "SEND_ORDER_SUCCESS") {
    return {
      status: "SUCCESS",
      data: action.payload,
    };
  }
  return state;
};

export const makeOrder = (ingredientsIds) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: "SEND_ORDER_IS_LOADING",
  });

  const result = await fetch("https://norma.nomoreparties.space/api/orders", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({ ingredients: ingredientsIds }),
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .catch(() => null);

  if (!result || !result.success) {
    dispatch({
      type: "SEND_ORDER_FAILED",
    });
    return result;
  }
  dispatch({
    type: "SEND_ORDER_SUCCESS",
    payload: result,
  });
};
```

The button that trigger the request:

```
<Button
      disabled={selectedIngredientsIds.length === 0}
      htmlType="button"
      onClick={() => dispatch(makeOrder(selectedIngredientsIds))}
      type="primary"
      size="large"
      extraClass="mr-4" >
      Оформить заказ
    </Button>
```

This is the component that get the result of the request:

```
   export const OrderDetails = () => {
  const { status, data } = useAppSelector((store) => store.orderObject);

  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  if (status === "STALE" || status === "LOADING") {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Modal onClose={() => dispatch({ type: "SEND_ORDER_STALE" })}>
       {status === "FAILED" ? ("Ошибка") : (
        <>
          <p className={`${orderDetailsStyle.orderDetails__orderNumber} text text_type_digits-large mt-30 mb-8`}>{data?.order.number}</p>
          <p className="text text_type_main-medium mb-15">идентификатор заказа</p>
          <img src={done} alt="заказано" className={orderDetailsStyle.orderDetails__image}/>
          <p className="text text_type_main-default mb-2">Ваш заказ начали готовить</p>
          <p className="text text_type_main-default text_color_inactive mb-30">Дождитесь готовности на орбитальной станции</p>
        </>
      )}
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

How can i solve the problem?

Comment: If you get a 400 error, it comes from the backend. The what are the causes that can lead to a 400 error from your backend? Absolutely nothing related to react and redux :)

Comment: No idea, what can be the problem, i don't see any error in console and also in VScode .... someone have suggestions?

Comment: What's your backend?

Comment: i did't get exactly what you meant, the only thing that they gave me it's an URL and whit that url i should do the request

Comment: Then you should ask them or read the docs. Your code is correct. Either you missing data or their backend has a bug.

Comment: thanks for the answer,  i will try to ask and solve the situation with whom that gave me the url

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the code is right, i needed just to add to my request:

```js
headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
},
```

Answer (score 0):

A [400 Bad Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) simply means the request was bad. The server is saying something is wrong with what you sent it.

To test this outside of your app, in Firefox I use a free extension called `RESTED Client` to simply test a `POST` to your URL (`https://norma.nomoreparties.space/api/orders`) with the a pseudo body of `{ ingredients: ["1", "2"]}`. It returns the following:

```
{
  "success": false,
  "message": "Ingredient ids must be provided"
}
```

The problem is with the data you are sending. The reason I know this is because I repeated exactly what your app is doing here:

```js
const result = await fetch("https://norma.nomoreparties.space/api/orders", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({ ingredients: ingredientsIds }),
})
```

[image]